# Initial data from ListAdapter gets erased when using DiffUtil.ItemCallback

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-listadapter

In my app I have two LiveData objects, one for getting items from 0-10 and second to get the items from 11-20. I'm trying to load the data in a RecyclerView but instead of having 20 items, the first 10 (0-10) are replaces with new 10 (11-20). This is what I have tried:

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
adapter = new ItemsAdapter();
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ItemListViewModel.class);
```

To get items from 0-10 I use this method:

```
private void getInitialItems() {
    ItemListLiveData liveData = viewModel.getItemsLiveData();
    liveData.observe(this, itemtList -> adapter.submitList(itemtList));
}
```

To get items from 11-20 I use this method:

```
private void getNextlItems() {
    ItemListLiveData liveData = viewModel.getItemsLiveData();
    liveData.observe(this, itemtList -> adapter.submitList(itemtList));
}
```

This is my ViewModel class:

```
public class ItemListViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private ItemListRepository repository = new ItemListRepository();

    ItemListLiveData getItemsLiveData() {
        return repository.getItemListLiveData();
    }
}
```

In the repository I only get the items from a back-end server. This is my adapter class:

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends ListAdapter<Item, ItemsAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {
    ItemsAdapter() {
        super(diffCallback);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Inflate the view
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //Bind the Item according to position
    }

    private static DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item> diffCallback = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Item oldItem, @NonNull Item newItem) {
            return oldItem.id.equals(newItem.id);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Item oldItem, @NonNull Item newItem) {
            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        }
    };
}
```

My expectation is when using `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` to get both lists as a cumulative list since all the objects are different. Even if I pass both lists to the same adapter, I end up having only ten items (11-20). How to use `submit list` so I can have 20 items in my list and not only 10 (11-20)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DiffUtil.ItemCallback` is used for animating smoothly changes in dataset in adapter.

For example if you have have 10 items, than submit list with 9 items that were contained in previous 10, `DiffUtil.ItemCallback` will determine difference between old and new list, which position that element was and animate changes accordingly. What you are looking for in your case is [Pagination](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging) where you can expand/show items while scrolling.

You don't need two `LiveData` for this one, you cast fetch data from some source add it to `LiveData` of `Pagination`. First it will be showed 10 items, then if you scroll to end another 10, and so on. You can adjust type of pagination by your needs with provided `Configuration`.

To do all that without Pagination.

```
    liveData.observe(this, itemtList -> adapter.submitList(adapter.getCurrentList().addAll(itemtList)));
```

Get previous data, on top of that data add new data and it will all be shown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I need pagination. What do you mean with "with provided Configuration"?

Comment: ```private fun configurePagination(): PagedList.Config =
  PagedList.Config.Builder()
   .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
   .setPrefetchDistance(1)
   .setPageSize(PAGE_SIZE_TOP_NEWS)
   .build()
```

Things like this, I might have not expressed my thoughts that well. :)

Comment: Ok thanks but in my case, is there any possibility to have both lists in a single one?

Comment: In background this is how Pagination works:
- You fetch items from source (let's say remote api), you get list of 100 items
- You configure your pagination to show 10 items
- Your UI loads 10 items, after you scroll a bit it shows 10 more items and so on it shows only needed number on items by scrolling.

You can add more items manually, but I don't see need for that. I can image use case where you fetch from remote api 100 items, and add on top of that 50 items from database, and that you can do.

Best part is that you don't have to worry about representation

Comment: Ok, I understand you. I just asked you if there is any possibility to have both lists in a single one using my code? If yes, what should I do to achieve that?

Comment: It is possible, I edited answer with line you should change. I might have made error in typing, but concept is the same.

Comment: There is no [getCurrentList()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter) in ListAdapter class. Can you check it please?

Comment: Then you are not using androidx ListAdapter.
Okay, you can add field in adapter `private List<Item> dataset = new ArrayList<Item>();` , then override in adapter function submitList(). 
body of overriden function should now be `{ dataset.addAll(listFromFunc); super.submitList(dataset) }` which means that you are adding new items to previous list, and then submiting that list which contains old+new items.